# Elasticbeanstalk Customize Nginx through ebextension

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have been literally all day fighting with this, I just need to increase the **client_max_body_size** in my Nginx Configuration.

I have a tomcat configuration (custom ami) and I tried this so far.

- creating a file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my-http.conf
- creating a file in /tmp and then move it to the above location
- creating the filesystem in my source code
  *.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/my-http.conf*

Here is the latest (desperate) file I tested (named *.ebextensions/http_conf.config*)

```
files:
  "/tmp/http.conf.tmp" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 10M;

  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 20M;      

container_commands:
  01_remove_current_http_conf:
    command: "rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/http.conf"
  02_cp_new_http_conf:
    command: "cp /tmp/http.conf.tmp /tmp/http.conf.tmp2"
  03_cp_new_http_conf2:
    command: "cp /tmp/http.conf.tmp /etc/nginx/conf.d/http.conf"
```

So as you can see, I'm trying everything, let me share the results of this.

- I can see a file created at /tmp/http.conf.tmp
- I can't see a file created at /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
- I can see a file created at /tmp/http.conf.tmp2
- I can't see a file created at /etc/nginx/conf.d/http.conf

I'm guessing the directory is overwritten after I create those files somehow, but I couldn't find a way to avoid that.

Comment: /var/log/eb-activity.log may have clues...

Comment: /var/log/eb-activity.log may have clues? Also try both different types here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951706/32453

Answer (score 0):

Create `.config` file extension that you place in a folder named `.ebextensions` and deploy in your application source bundle. 
Please refer [client-max-body-size-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) 
and  [Beanstalk Configuration Files (.ebextensions)](https://medium.com/@marilu597/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c)

Comment: Isn't that what I just did? can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Yes, it seems same. Please check permission of `http_conf.config` file as mentioned in link

Comment: the http_conf.config looks like it is overwritten, as I mentioned in my original question, so the permissions don't matter actually, do they?

Comment: This file has the mode set to `000644` and the owner and group set to root, when we do a `ls -l` for this file, the result will be: `-rw-r--r--1` root root  `http_conf.config`